# Powershell ews script to read mail from my mailbox is retrieving values for FROM and SUBJECT but is not returning anything for mail body

Tags: powershell, email, exchangewebservices

I have written a powershell script to return the FROM, SUBJECT and mail body from the latest mail from my outlook exchange mailbox. The script is returning the FROM and SUBJECT but nothing for the mail body. Below is my code snippet

```
$findResults=$inbox.FindItems(1)
foreach ($item in $findResults.Items)
{
    "From: $($item.From.Name)"
    "Subject: $($item.Subject)"
    "Body: $($Item.Body.Text)"
    $item.From.Name| Out-File 'D:\newsample.txt'
    $item.Subject| Out-File 'D:\newsample.txt' -Append
    $item.Body.Text| Out-File 'D:\newsample.txt' -Append
}
```

There is no output for mail body in console nor in file.
Please help me out in sorting out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `PropertySet` to access the `Body` property, as it's not available from the `FindItems` call.

```
$psPropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$psPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;
```

and then load the `PropertySet` to get the `Body`

```
$item.load($psPropertySet)
```